# How to prepare an SQL query with optional clauses in java?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I encounter a little issue with the preparedStatement object in java. I have a GUI with several JTextField (and other thing), a JTable, and a button. The JTable is constructed using an SQL request on my database, something like this :

```
SELECT date, item, vendor FROM Sells;
```

**I want to use the JTextFields to filter the results when the user click the button.** Say we have a JTextField for the date, an other for the item, another for the vendor.

If all the fields are filled, I can use a prepared query, like this:

```
String query = "SELECT date, item, vendor FROM Sells WHERE date > ? AND item = ? AND vendor = ?";
PreparedStatement prepared = this.connect.prepareStatement(query);
prepared.setString(1, (String)dateField.getText());
prepared.setString(2, (String)itemField.getText());
prepared.setString(3, (String)vendorField.getText());
```

This (with some adjustements like a try/catch, variables declarations etc) works well. **My issue is to manage the possibility for the user to filter using only a few fields (for example only the date, or the date and the item but not the vendors).** For now, I can't find an other way than:

1) test the content of each field with an if statement, and modify the "query" variable in consequence.

2) use another complicated if/else structure in order to determine which variables are to filter with, and which "prepared.set...." should be used. It's tricky, since sometimes it will be a String, but sometimes an int or anything else. And of course, determine the index is also a little problem cause it wont be the same eveytime.

I feel like I'm missing something, and I shouldn't use this weird solution with multiple if/else. Can anyone help me ? Is there a simpler solution, or is it just a situation where I have to do it the hard way ?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can thinking of creating a dynamic query with only the input parameter

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Thank you, I am a beginner and I didn't know about dynamic SQL. It seems to be a good idea, I will search how to use it.

Comment: You can use MyBatis library for this.

Comment: @WW. tank you for your advice. I would prefer if I can find an option where I don't have to learn so much new things. Looking for both solutions mentioned, it seems it will take me hours to understand how this works (I am not a professional programmer, and I already am struggling with java and sql :) ). Does this mean that no solution to this kind of issue exists in "basic java+sql"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing the query statement with just the columns you need is probably the most efficient approach.  But you can also do something like this:

```
WHERE (date > ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
      (item = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
      (vendor = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

This requires providing each parameter twice and assumes that the "empty" value is the SQL `NULL`.

This is a case where named parameters simplify things:

```
WHERE (date > :date OR :date IS NULL) AND
      (item = :item OR :item IS NULL) AND
      (vendor = :vendor OR :vendor IS NULL)
```

Comment: So much tanks, this is exactly what I need! I don't actually understand your first proposition about "constructing the query with just the columns [I] need", did you mean code the multiple if/else I mentionned? Anyway, your second solution seems very ok to me, so I'll try that. Now I have to translate this in my application, but I should be ok with that. Thanks again!